# InfoPath is Dead

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, sharepoint-online

As per [this](http://blogs.office.com/2014/01/31/update-on-infopath-and-sharepoint-forms/) Microsoft blog article, InfoPath is retiring. It will not be available in the next version of SharePoint.

I am in the middle of setting up a Forms Solution architecture for a company and don't want my client to invest in a technology which is soon retiring.

Can someone suggest a better alternative which should work on both Online and Offline version of SharePoint and looks promising for the future 3-5 years at least?

Comment: Here is an approach we developed to phase out our InfoPath forms using SharePoint lists: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/140095/how-can-lists-be-made-to-support-master-detail-relationships

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to take a look at [Nintex Forms](http://www.nintex.com/en-US/Products/Pages/NintexForms.aspx).

It replaces InfoPath Forms Services to some extent, Nintex Forms is a web based designer that enables forms to be created within SharePoint.

The following products are currently available:

- [Nintex Forms](http://www.nintex.com/en-US/Products/Pages/NintexForms.aspx)
- [Nintex Forms for Office 365](http://www.nintex.com/en-US/Products/Pages/NFO365.aspx)

[image]

P.S. Disclosure, i do not work  at Nintex company

Answer (score 8):

Per that same article, Microsoft has indicated they will support InfoPath 2013 until 2023 and that they are working to provide migration guidance from InfoPath into whatever successor technology or technologies based on Office and/or SharePoint may take its place. If you have a 3-5 year time horizon, I wouldn't rule out InfoPath completely. It would seem that solutions developed in InfoPath 2013 would have the greatest chance of a smooth, successful migration to whatever replaces it.

Comment: I agree with Danny, I strongly suggest using InfoPath, if that's what your company requirements call for. It's still a great product and 10 years is a long life for any product version.

Answer (score 1):

Really, your worried about InfoPath now?  Don't kill your solution yet, Why not wait until 2023 instead when support runs out.  I would bet by then the business process would have changed anyway and another solution would be required, in which case you'll be looking at yet another product after the InfoPath replacement (that is, if your not retired by then :-) )

Bismarck